# How to clear or remove a class in angular 6 through [ngClass]

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have 2 tabs,onclick a tab1 a div will be shown, again on click toggle button the div will expand(100% width) and collapse(25% width) by changing the class. Again when I click on tab2, and then click on tab1 my div should be remain collapse always,I mean its class should be 'old'.Here is the code below.

### app.component.html

```
<span style="cursor:pointer" (click) = "tab1()">Tab1</span>&nbsp;<span (click) = "tab2()" style="cursor:pointer">Tab2</span>
<div  [ngClass]="{'old': toggle, 'new': !toggle}" *ngIf="show" class="old">
  Hello
</div>
<button (click)="change()">change</button>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  toggle:boolean = true;
  show:any;
tab1(){
    alert('tab1');
    this.show = true;
}
tab2(){
    alert('tab2');
    this.show = true;
}
  change(){
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
this.show = false;
  }
}
```

### app.component.css

```
.old{
    width:25%;
    border:1px solid;
    height:200px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:yellow;
}
.new{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid;
    height:200px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:green;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div  [ngClass]="toggle ? 'old' : 'new'" *ngIf="show">
     Hello
</div>
```

Removed the `class="old"`. Please check now.

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpehqb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: you may not need class="old" in this case

Comment: Its not working , if click on tab1 second time ,I mean after clicking on tab2 ,my expanded div should be changed to original position I mean to 'old' class.

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER Please check the stackblitz demo added in answer.

Comment: same issue like earlier. Suppose I expand the div onclick of 'change' button and then if I go to tab2,and again click on tab1 the div is still expanded,it should actually change the class to 'old'

Comment: Did you checked the stackblitz demo? As this is what I am understanding based on this as the div must toggle from 25% to 100% and viceversa based on button click